# JavaScript attribute is undefined. What?

Tags: javascript

I read a User object (attrs : id, userName) from the session scope in JavaScript (AngularJS) in a JSP page. It is successfully because it appears right in the console. But when I want to access its attributes the browser says these are undefined.

The JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module( "appUserOrders", [] );
    app.controller( "ctrlUserOrders", 
    function ($scope, $http ) 
    {
        $scope.user = '<%= session.getAttribute("User") %>';
        console.log( $scope.user );
        console.log( $scope.user.id );
        console.log( $scope.user.userName );
    } 
    );

</script>
```

The console contents:

`User(id=1111, userName=TestUserName)
userorders.html:29 undefined
userorders.html:30 undefined`

How can I access its attribute values because the `user.id` is needed for the `REST` call as a `@PathVariable`. Why does it not work? What does the `session.getAttribute( key )` give back?

Thanks in advance for the replies!

Comment: You're trying to retrieve those properties from a string.

Comment: `session.getAttribute(key)` obviously returns a string that looks like `User(id=1111, userName=TestUserName)`. As this is no valid JSON, it will not help to remove the single quotes `'`.

Comment: `$scope.user` is a string.
you should convert the value from `session.getAttribute` to object

Comment: @Teemu And how should I get the User Object from the session, not just as a String? Or how can I convert the String to an Object?

Answer (score 0):

After the useful comments I created a method in the `User` class called `toJSONString()` and put its result into the session. It worked fine, but I changed my mind because there is no place for a JSON string in the session scope. So I send the userID as a model attribute from the `userOrders.jsp` page `HTTP` `GET` method `controller` and I does not use the `session` at all.

The controller method:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/userorders", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String userOrdersHandler_GET( Model model_ )
{
  // Constant value just for test cases
  model_.addAttribute( "userID", 1111 );
  return "ordering/userorders";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var userID = '${userID}';
$scope.orders = [];
$http( get( "/appname/users/" + userID + "/orders.json" ) ).then( function ( response ) { $scope.orders = respond.data; }, function ( respond ) { console.log( "..." ) } );
```

Thanks for the replies!